# Unable to setup compose for web project with intelliJ IDE

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, compose-multiplatform, compose-for-web

I want to build a website using kotlin and the compose for web framework. For that I just used the intelliJ project creation wizard like this :

[image]

Then I just clicked the button Run 'build.gradle.kts' and I had this message :

```
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how to solve this error. I already tried to include the kotlin.scripting.compiler in the project using project structure settings but nothing happened.

[EDIT]

I found that I'm able to launch the project and display a page on localhost thanks to gradle tasks. These tasks are available in the gradle tool window:
[image]

I used the 'jsBrowserRun' task to launch the app. There is a lot of scripts available and I have no idea what the majority of them does. Also I don't know in which file these tasks are located, I would appreciate if someone know where they are. Finally, I want to have a better understanding of this framework, it provides me a UI whith generated HTML and javascript but how am I supposed to build my server around it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-16451. Feel free to follow it.

Comment: I already seen this post from youtrack. But it didn't help. I can launch different tasks from the Gradle tool window but how can I run my project ?

Comment: Also, where can I locate all these scripts visible in the Gradle tool window ?

Comment: To run the project, you can use jsBrowserRun task.

Comment: Yes, I understood that we could launch the project on a browser with this task. Now I'll try to run it on a server.